# Angular using service in object or create object with service in constructor

Tags: angular

I have a form setting:

```
export const fields = [
  {
     key: 'key',
     options: myService.get() // how can I call service method here?
  }
]
```

I'm wondering about something like this:

```
class MyFields {
  fields = [
    {
       key: 'key',
       options: this.myService.get()
    }
  ]
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
}

@Component...
export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
      const fields = new MyFields().fields;
    }
}
```

But I have to pass service to the:

```
new MyFields().fields;
```

constructor.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `MyFields` already accepts service in its constructor, now you just need to call

```
new MyFields(passedService).fields;
```

That's it really.

Comment: But I don't want to pass this service here. MyComponent is a child class and I have to call super before. So I can't use 'this' in MyCompoent constructor to pass this.passedService

Comment: Why not? You can have a child class that calls super and has its own injected services. The bottom line is - if you want to use a service inside `MyFields` class you have to either inject it into it, which you already do in its constructor, or make the service a global variable (bad idea) so you can use it without injecting.

Answer (score 0):

you can also call service function from `ngOnInit()`

```
class MyFields {
fields = [
  {
     key: 'key',
     options:''
  }
]
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  const fields = new MyFields(this.myService).fields;
}    

// Another way 
ngOnInit(){
    this.fields[0].options = this.myService.get();
}
```